# How do I remove the warning from a EasyMock.anyObject(List.class) call

Tags: java, generics, warnings, easymock

Compiler can't stop complaining with this call :

```
EasyMock.anyObject(List.class)
```

I tried to specify list's type

```
EasyMock.anyObject(List<MyType>.class)
```

but it doesn't seems to be an option (anyway, it is stupid since java will erase the type during the compilation)

Is there a clean way (@SuppressWarning is not a clean way IMO) to remove this warning?

Thank you

Comment: what warning? and which compiler?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's not possible. I'll call it a generic limitation. Sadly it's not always possible to remove a warning for some perfectly normal usage (like using the class of a generic class).

However, with EasyMock you can do the following:

```
EasyMock.<List<MyType>> anyObject()
```

which will do the same thing but without warning. The anyObject you used exist because it's a bit more readable and allows static imports.

Comment: +1 Although it seems like this is removing the check on the _type_ of the parameter, EasyMock doesn't do that check anyway.  So to EasyMock, this is equivalent.

Comment: Is there an available reference or broader explanation of what the syntax above is actually doing?

Comment: If you are on Java 8 and above, just using `EasyMock.anyObject()` will work.

Answer (score 4):

Only as suggestion :

```
interface A extends List<MyType> {};
EasyMock.anyObject(A.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the Hamcrest matcher `isA()`, instead of `anyObject()`. The difference between them is that `isA`-matcher checks the values on `null`, unlike `anyObject`.
You can learn more about those matchers [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html)

Comment: No, you cannot use a hamcrest matcher in an easymock expectation.